# A complete free guide for game development in Python or C#

Tags: python, games, c#, opengl

That's what i know:

- C#;
- Python;
- What is OpenGl;
- What is SDL (barely);

Now i'd like to make a sketch for a 2D platform game ( i.e. a ball that has to avoid some obstacles till reaches the end of the level ) in order to understand how does a game works (physics, events, collisions, drawing, sprites).
So the question is:
**WHERE TO START?**
I need a book, a pdf, a website that says to me

> "Open monodevelop, start a new project
>   then this is the skeleton of main
>   class. Now you need to manage physics
>   in this way. As physics are finished
>   you need to care about level drawing
>   in this way. Now you need to create
>   sprites in this way..."

I'm also searching for team-mates or someone that wants to start this "adventure" with me.

Comment: This should be on stack overflow.

Comment: In fact we have a Game Development Stack Exchange site now: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Nothing from this question is specific to Ubuntu - While development/programming questions related to Ubuntu are considered on topic this question does not seem to fit that scope.

Answer (score 3):

I agree that you'll probably get better feedback on StackOverflow but as a StackOverflower, myself, I can suggest one thing: [pygame](http://www.pygame.org).

It's a framework that on the surface looks a bit silly but it actually hooks straight into SDL and has multiple graphics fallbacks. It does a lot of the heavy lifting for you and while that might not be what you want in the long run, I couldn't think of anything better for getting started.

They also have few well explained tutorials, including one about [how to make a "punch the chimp" annoying-advert style game](http://www.pygame.org/docs/tut/chimp/ChimpLineByLine.html).

Answer (score 1):

There are some [tutorials & libraries listed on the Python wiki](http://wiki.python.org/moin/GameProgramming).